# what is the error in my code ? trying to buid 2D matrix

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix, runtime-error, multidimensional-array

i am creating a program that create a 2D matrix using java it suppose to build a 2D array after it check if the numbers are prime or no.

i know that the error is in the for loop of the **createMatrix Function**  and i hope that someone can help me and explain where is my error and how to fix it.

the system display this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at test6.test6.createMatrix(Question6.java:26)
    at test6.test6.main(Question6.java:52)
```

## and this is my code :

```
package test6;

public class test6 {

    public static int isPrimeNumber(int number) {
        if (number == 2 || number == 3) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
        for (int i = 3; i < sqrt; i += 2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static int[][] createMatrix(int[][] m) {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(m[i][j]);
            }

        }
        return m;

    }

    public static String toString(int[][] m) {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
            int r[] = m[row];
            for (int col = 0; col < r.length; col++) {
                if (col > 0)
                    text.append(", ");
                text.append(r[col]);
            }
            text.append("\n");
        }
        return text.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] num = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 } };

        System.out.println(toString(createMatrix(num)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see exactly where the array index goes out of bounds

Comment: With Javas pretty stack traces you don't need a debugger for that.

Comment: A debugger is overkill here, as @aioobe says. Look at the line the stack trace points to. There's your error. If you need to debug it, add some prints around the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've swapped the indexes the other way around:

```
for (i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++) {    // i runs over the columns of first row
    for (j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {   // j runs over the rows
        System.out.println(m[i][j]);   // here i is the row, and j is the column!
    }
}
```

A better way to loop over the matrix is:

```
for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {        // let i run over the rows
    for (j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) { // let j run over the columns
        System.out.println(m[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really a proper way, sometimes you want a length first sweep, other times a depth first sweep.  One isn't really better than the other (unless the algorithim requires a particular direction)

Comment: Reformulated the answer.

Comment: I still think that if you're going to make a bold statement that it's better, you should specify in what way it is better.  Otherwise it's all "taking it on faith" without direction as to why it is an improvement.

Comment: It's better because it avoids ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. Not a very bold statement imo.

Comment: true, not a bold statement; but, one that wasn't made until now.

Comment: That's not a _better_ way, it's a _correct_ way. Semantics :p

Comment: now it work thank you but i have a different problem now how to check if the number in the matrix is prime or not...using the isPrimeNumber() function ?

Comment: Please post another question (and put the link here in the comment if you like me to look at it).

Comment: i am not able to do it be cause the website say that i am only able to post once every 90 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You are transversing your `m X n` array n times down the m direction and m times down the n direction.

As a result, within `createMatrix(...)` you run a good chance of walking out of the array (unless it is a square array).  Also, `createMatrix` is a horrible name for something that just prints out a matrix created elsewhere.